# Postcodes for roads in London

Tags: data-request, uk, city, postal-code

I have asked this on GIS and been referred here

First time asking, couldn't see a starting point to read from. I'm doing a lookup by road name (London) to get the Postcode (first part W1 / WC1H etc), i'm a 1/4 through and it has taken days to do it manually, I really need to find a source where I can get London Road names and their Postcode, (would be better if I can get the A and B road designations) can someone point me to a resource and code I can use to preform a download that will ultimately go into Excel. I don't how to change / understand overpass to even make a start. I don't mind duplicates in the data I can clean that

i.e. STRAND, WC1, A4

Answer (score 0):

Ordnance Survey's Open Names dataset contains roads in Great Britain along with the postcode district (or outcode) that road falls within:

https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-government/products/open-map-names

Comment: Thank you Dan, Is there a way to combine the data, I can see it holds what I want but I need a reliable way to derive it to one line answers ? some sort of interface that can do that conversion

Comment: Partly solved using powerquery, but its not perfect

Comment: Each line contains a road name and an outcode (e.g. "Woodcote Road" and "RG4"), so I'm not completely clear what you mean? Some roads are sufficiently long to traverse multiple outcodes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the gis data why not try extract centroids and bulk feed them into http://postcodes.io/ to get the postcode? Done in seconds...

But a single road is unlikely to have just a single post code in dense urban areas?